# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.linq.iqueryable anonymous type#1' to byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, select, byte

![Here is the class code:][1]

---

```
byte[] Answer_Context;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfRows; i++)
        {
            Answer_Context[i]= (from mt in db.Answers where mt.AssignmentID.Equals(QueryString_assignmentID) select new {mt.AnswerContext});
           s3eed[i] = Answer_Context;
```

---

Hint : (AnswerContext Is NVarBinary Field in My DataBase )
this linq query should returns more than columns, so i used (Select new) .. 
.

Why Select New does not work correctly !!

Comment: try this edit Answer_Context[i]= (from mt in db.Answers where mt.AssignmentID.Equals(QueryString_assignmentID).FirstorDefault();

Comment: @FerasSalim that's not going to work without a `select`.  Though you could do `db.Answers.FirstOrDefault(mt => mt.AssignmentID.Equals(QueryString_assignmentID);` instead.  But then you're returning an `Answer`, not a `byte`.

Comment: @juharr sorry I forget the syntax

Answer (score 0):

`select new` will result in an anonymous class.  Just select the column that should be a `byte` instead and `.ToArray` if you want the results in an array.  I also don't see any reason for the `for` loop.

```
byte[] Answer_Context = (from mt in db.Answers 
                         where mt.AssignmentID.Equals(QueryString_assignmentID) 
                         select mt.AnswerContext).ToArray();
```